# How to use Python decode multiple json object with it in one json file

Tags: python, json, object

Iam a new gay about programmer, I use this code:

`with codecs.open('test.json', 'a', 'utf-8') as jsonfile:
    jsonfile.write(json.dumps(line, sort_keys = True, indent = 4) + '\n')`

storage data in the jsonfile like this:

[image]

But When I want load() or loads() the data back in ram with follow "code 1" :

```
with codecs.open('test.json', 'r', 'utf-8') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    print data
```

It raise: "ValueError: Extra data: line 20 column 1"

So, I change the "code 2":

```
with codecs.open('test.json', 'r', 'utf-8') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        data = json.loads(line)
        print data
```

It raise: "ValueError: Expecting object: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

But if I just sotrage "Json object one" in the jsonfile and used the "code 1", it work well. So can any help how to decode multiple json object in one json file? Thank you very much.

Comment: Either *don't add newlines in each JSON object* (don't indent), and use [Loading and parsing a JSON file in Python](//stackoverflow.com/a/12451465), or use [How do I use the 'json' module to read in one JSON object at a time?](//stackoverflow.com/a/21709058). But mostly don't use multiple JSON objects per file.

Comment: OK.It confused me a few days. Thank you, Sir. Have a nice day.